# Do I need to manually clear cached values in APC after source code changes

Tags: php, caching, apc

For example, for the follow code,

```
if (apc_fetch('foo') === false) {
    apc_add('foo', 'bar');
}
```

If I commit new code, replacing `apc_add('foo', 'bar');` with `apc_add('foo', 'no-bra');`. Do I need to manually clear APC cache to avoid outdated cached value? Does the same rule apply to EAccelerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is nothing that is going to guess that you want to violate the rule of your cache setting routine.  For development I typically put the apc.php script that comes with apc in webspace and use that for administration.